# Is the "NULL" or "\0"-sign, of a Null-terminated string, stored in a file?

Tags: c++, c, string, file, null

If i want to store a Null-terminated string into a file, and the file will only containing that string, is the "\0" or "NULL"-character stored in the file (before the "EOF" (End of File)-sign)?

Furthermore: Is the result depended from the operation system and so on the compiler, on which i will compile the source code on?

Comment: It's up to you.  You can store it or not, depending on how you write the code.  The answer (the right way to do it) might depend on the expectations of any code that wil be reading the file.

Comment: If you write `fprintf(fp, "%s", string)` or `fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fp)` or `write(fd, str, strlen(str))`, it will not write the `\0`.  But if you had `char str[] = "Hello, world!"` followed by `fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str), fp)` or `write(fd, str, sizeof(str))`, it *would* write the '\0'.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for the information, Steve. I have confused that in the running case.

Comment: I have definitely used (and implemented) file formats where the `\0` *was* deliberately, explicitly stored.

Comment: You can store the 0x00 byte but it is not necessary. Even if the strings are 2 or more, the normal separator is one of: new line (LF), tab or comma. You can also define your own code for string separator (end of string marker). For example function `fgets` reads string until new line (LF) or EOF.

Comment: I've seen apps that store the NUL string terminator in their files.  But not all filesystems store an explicit EOF marker in the file (some do, but not the ones prevalent on personal computers).

Comment: Remember than `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant. To avoid confusion, don't use the word NULL to refer to the null character. It's NUL or just `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to write null characters to a text file, but you almost certainly don't want to.

A *string* (defined as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character") is an in-memory data format.

A *text stream* consists of a sequence of *lines*:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into
>   *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a
>   terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.

A string may or may not contain a single line of text. If it represents a line of text, it may or may not include the terminating new-line `'\n'` character (you'll need to keep track of that yourself).

If you have a sequence of strings in memory, the usual way to write them to a text file is to write the contents of each string, *not including the terminating null character*, to the file, adding a new-line character if necessary. Functions like `fprintf` and `fputs` assume their arguments are *strings*, so they take care of omitting the `'\0'`.

You *can* write a null character to a text stream, but it's implementation-defined what will actually be written to the file. You can write a null character, or any byte value, to a binary stream -- but then you can't safely use string functions (`strlen()` et al, or even `fgets()` and `fputs()`) on data written to or read from the stream. (And in practice, *most* systems allow null characters to be written to and read from text files -- though a number of standard library functions assume that text files contain only printable characters.)

Comment: "You can write a null character to a text stream, but it's implementation-defined what will actually be written to the file." --> Wow, found "Characters
may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing
conventions for representing text in the host environment." C11 §7.21.2 2.  What a wide spec hole to drive through.

Answer (score 2):

`'\0'` is not a printing character so if you use an io stream in text mode, then whether it will be preserved when you write it to a file through such a stream is implementation-dependent.

[7.21.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p2)

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into
>   lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a
>   terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a
>   terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters
>   may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to
>   conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host
>   environment. Thus, there need not be a one- to-one correspondence
>   between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily
>   compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream
>   only if: the data consist only of printing characters and the control
>   characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is
>   immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a
>   new-line character. Whether space characters that are written out
>   immediately before a new-line character appear when read in is
>   implementation-defined.

If you write the `'\0'` to a file through a binary stream (one opened with e.g., `fopen("file","wb")`), e.g., with `fputc('\0',f)` or `fwrite("",1,1,f)`, you should be able to get it back.

Comment: First thank you very much for your answer, PSkocik. I made a mistake i meant of course "\0" not "/0" for NULL. I´ve edited my question up this way. Hope it doesn´t make any change to your answer. So in result, you mean it is based on the implementation used and whether i write the string through a binary stream or not?

Comment: @RobertS Yes. If you're using a text stream and you're actually writing the terminating `'\0'`, the result is implementation-defined. A binary stream should preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the functions that write a string to a file will not include the terminating null. You can write a null to a file using a function that takes a byte count, but that doesn't make sense because there's no corresponding read function.

Comment: Um, yes, there is: `fread()` will read any kind of binary data including nulls.

Comment: @TomZych: There's no standard function that specifically reads data terminated by a null byte.

Comment: @KeithThompson : But Mark said there was no _read_ function corresponding to a _write_ function that takes a _byte count_, when there clearly is.  The statement _"that doesn't make sense because there's no corresponding read function"_ is clearly false.  That said writing a NUL in a _text_ file certainly makes no sense.

Comment: @TomZych sorry I was unclear, you're obviously correct that `fread` can do it - if you know ahead of time how many bytes you need. But there's no easy way to know that, nor is there a way to read until you reach a null.

Comment: Yes, I see, we were talking about two different things.